# Como criar um "Area" no MVC no .net core 3.1?

Tags: mvc, .net-core

O caminho para criar uma Area não aparece mais no .net core 3.1

Caminho: Projeto > botão direito > Add > Area

Comment: Conseguiu verificar a resposta? Não esqueça de aceitá-la caso  esteja satisfeita com a mesma.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação do framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1), para criar uma área é preciso:

- A estrutura de diretórios com as áreas (necessário somente para views)
- Controllers decorados com `[Area("nome da área")]`
- Criação da rota no startup

**Exemplo de estrutura**

```
Project name
  Areas
    Products
      Controllers
        ManageController.cs
      Views
        Home
          Index.cshtml
        Manage
          Index.cshtml
```

**Exemplo de controller**

```
[Area("Products")]
public class ManageController : Controller
{
```

**Configuração no startup**

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "Products",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Projeto > Add > New Scaffolded Item > MVC Area